# delete selected checkbox in repeater

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a repeater with checkbox in it and I want to delete subcategories the items/records from table which are selected with checkbox in to it. any ideas?

**TABLE STRUCTURE:**
software
`CategoryID=100, SubCategoryID=NULL (main category)
ASP.NET
CategoryID=100, SubCategoryID=100 (sub category)`

**I got error:**

> Incorrect syntax near '='.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='.

```
// select all
 protected void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rpCategory.Items)
        {
 CheckBox checkBoxApproved = ri.FindControl("checkBoxApproved") as CheckBox;
            if (checkBoxApproved != null)
            {
                if (checkBoxApproved.Checked == true)
                {
                    checkBoxApproved.Checked = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    checkBoxApproved.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // delete all
     protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rpCategory.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)
                rpCategory.Items[i].FindControl("checkBoxApproved");

                if (((CheckBox)rpCategory.Items[i].FindControl("checkBoxApproved")).Checked)
                {
                    CheckBox CheckBox = (CheckBox)rpCategory.Items[i].FindControl("checkBoxApproved");

                    SqlConnection cnn = system.baglan();
                     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TBLCATEGORIES where  SubCategoryID="+CategoryID, cnn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Response.Redirect("SubCategories.aspx?Message=Success!");
               }
          }
```

Comment: Adr Space after and after SubCategoryID and check value of CategoryID

Comment: You need to change `SubCategoryID=+"CategoryID` to `SubCategoryID="+CategoryID`! The `+` is on the wrong side of the `"`. And I wonder if/why this compiles...

Answer (score 1):

Your following line has an error in it

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TBLCATEGORIES where  `SubCategoryID=+"CategoryID, cnn);`
```

Change  it to

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TBLCATEGORIES where  SubCategoryID=" +CategoryID, cnn);
```

Comment: what is the value of CategoryID and its value came from where in your btnSecilenleriSil_Click method ?

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSecilenleriSil" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" runat="server" onclick="btnSecilenleriSil_Click">Seçilenleri Sil</asp:LinkButton>

Comment: what is the value of CategoryID ?

Comment: im using unlimited categories with recursive function

Comment: CategoryID  should have only one value in delete query.

Comment: how can i this query

Comment: You can delete by multiple categoryIds by using query like DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: For multiple values of CategoryIds, you can use code like this if categoryId is a list

    for(int i =0; i<CategoryID.Count, i++)
    {
       SqlConnection cnn = system.baglan();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TBLCATEGORIES where  SubCategoryID="+CategoryID[i], cnn);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

Comment: I can't find out how you have filled values for CategoryID in the code you provided, please provide additional code.

Comment: there was an error about i<CategoryID.Count,i++: `Error: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'`